# One big update query, or several single update queries, to update a value in MySQL multi-tenant database

Tags: php, mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm working in a 'point of sale' application (PHP + MySQL), with products, sales, product quantity that have to be updated (+ or -) depending on the operation (sale/buy), etc.

On every sale/buy, I save the operation data (date, customer, totals...) in an 'invoices' table, and the details (all products in the invoice) in a 'invoicecontents' table.

Ok, you got it.

Now (and it works fine), I do the following to save the invoice and update products quantity:

1. Save the invoice data
2. Iterate the products in the invoice (from a JSON) and create a single INSERT query to save the invoice contents in second table.
3. AFTER THAT, once the invoice and details are saved, then I update products quantities WITH A SINGLE QUERY.

Something like this (for a sale operation):

```sql
UPDATE products a 
   SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY -
         (SELECT sum(QUANTITY) 
            FROM details b 
           WHERE IDPRODUCT = a.ID   
             and IDCUSTOMER = 4 
             and IDMOV = 615 
             and IDPRODUCT <> -1)
 where ID in 
         (SELECT IDPRODUCT 
            FROM details b 
           WHERE b.IDPRODUCT = a.ID 
             and IDCUSTOMER = 4 
             and IDMOV = 615 
             and IDARTICULO <> -1) 
   and IDCUSTOMER = 4 
   and a.ACTSTOCK = 1;
```

This works fine. **Of course all is in a "begin_transaction...commit"**.

HOWEVER, I would like to know if this second method is better, faster or even more *secure*:

1. Save the invoice data
2. Iterate the products in the invoice (from a JSON) and...
3. Inside the iteration, **for each product** (each json item):
   3.1. save that line into the invoice contents table
   3.2. update that product quantity in the products table for THAT product.

Something like this, for each product/item:

```sql
INSERT INTO detailtable
(IDCUSTOMER,IDPRODUCT,QUANTITY......)
VALUES
(4,615,5);

UPDATE products 
SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - 5
WHERE 
    IDPRODUCT = 615   
    and IDCUSTOMER = 4
    and ACTSTOCK = 1;
```

Maybe this second approach is simpler and more *undertandable*, but I really don't know if this will cause more (or less) CPU, memory consumption, taking into account that it is a multi-tenant database/application.

The problem I have with the first method is that, in the future, I will need to update more fields and tables with each product sold, so the big update query will be even bigger and even not possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, single queries are generally more efficient than multiple queries, all other things being equal. But either approach should work. Clarity and readability of code are vital to long-lived SQL-using applications.

If you do choose multiple queries, always process your products in the same order: always sort the list of items in your JSON objects in `ID` order before working through them one-by-one. This will help avoid deadlocks in your transactions.

In either case, but especially the multi-query case, take care to create efficient indexes for the WHERE clauses in all the queries within your transactions. The less time a transaction takes, the better.

**Edit** One more thing to do for best performance and fewest deadlocks.

Right after you begin your transaction, lock the rows in `products` you want to update in the transaction. Run this SELECT query -- it is very similar to the UPDATE query you showed us. You don't need its resultset, just the `FOR UPDATE` clause.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM (
    SELECT ID 
      FROM products
     WHERE ID in 
             (SELECT IDPRODUCT 
                FROM details b 
               WHERE b.IDPRODUCT = a.ID 
                 and IDCUSTOMER = 4 
                 and IDMOV = 615 
                 and IDARTICULO <> -1) 
       
       and IDCUSTOMER = 4 
       and a.ACTSTOCK = 1
     ORDER BY ID
       FOR UPDATE
) subq;
```

The FOR UPDATE locks are released when you COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) the transaction.

The `ORDER BY ID` clause avoids deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  Use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE.

Also

```
products: INDEX(IDCUSTOMER, IDPRODUCT, ACTSTOCK)
details:  INDEX(IDCUSTOMER, IDPRODUCT, IDMOV)
```